# Datos duplicados - Doble inner join

Tags: mysql

Tengo una duda sobre una consulta MYSQL.

Tengo las siguientes tablas:

```
tabla: partidos
id_partido,
id_local_partido,
id_visita_partido,
estado_partido,
rdolocal_partido,
rdovisita_partido,
cancha_partido,
hora_partido,
torneo_partido,
jornada_partido,
fecha_partido

tabla equipos
id_equipo,
nombre_equipo
```

El tema es, tengo que hacer una consulta que me tire la descripción del partido, pero no puedo hacer que me coloque, en vez de el id de equipo, el nombre... he intentado varios días pero estoy trabado.

Lo máximo que logre fue hacer 2 inner join pero me repite los registros.

```
SELECT partidos.* , equipos.* FROM partidos INNER JOIN equipos ON ( 
equipos.id_equipo LIKE partidos.id_local_partido ) OR (equipos.id_equipo 
LIKE partidos.id_visita_partido) WHERE partidos.jornada_partido = '1'
```

El resultado de esta consulta son 18 registros, pero necesito que sean 9  y que muestre el nombre del equipo LOCAL y del VISITANTE ya que son 9 partidos por jornada.

Necesito mostrar:

```
id_partido | LOCAL | rdolocal_partido | VISITANTE | rdovisita_partido | cancha | hora

1   |  RIVER   |    0     |   BOCA    |    0    | CANCHA 1  |  13:00hs
```

Espero haberme explicado, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu problema es este:

```
INNER JOIN equipos 
    ON ( equipos.id_equipo LIKE partidos.id_local_partido ) 
         OR 
      (equipos.id_equipo LIKE partidos.id_visita_partido)
```

Estás haciendo un `JOIN` por cada `partido` pero haces coincidir con dos filas de `equipos` por lo que naturalmente estás duplicando las filas.

Esto debería ser lo que buscas:

```
SELECT  p.id_partido, 
        l.nombre_equipo,
        p.rdolocal_partido,
        v.nombre_equipo,
        p.rdovisita_partido,
        p.cancha_partido, 
        p.hora_partido
        FROM partidos p
        INNER JOIN equipos l
              ON ( l.id_equipo = p.id_local_partido)
        INNER JOIN equipos v
              ON ( v.id_equipo = p.id_visita_partido)
        WHERE p.jornada_partido = '1'
```

Como puedes observar hacemos dos `INNER JOIN` para obtener los datos del equipo local y del visitante. También toma nota el uso de alias de tabla que hace mucho más sencilla la escritura. Y por último no parece que el `LIKE` sea el operador adecuado para hacer coincidir los `ID` de los equipos, imagino que el `=` es el adecuado.

Comment: Excelente respuesta!!! Definitivamente era lo que buscaba! Muchisimas gracias!!!

Dejo la consulta como queda identificando el Local y Visitante:

    SELECT p.id_partido, l.nombre_equipo AS LOCAL , p.rdolocal_partido, v.nombre_equipo AS Visitante, p.rdovisita_partido, p.cancha_partido, p.hora_partido FROM partidos p INNER JOIN equipos l ON ( l.id_equipo = p.id_local_partido ) INNER JOIN equipos v ON ( v.id_equipo = p.id_visita_partido ) WHERE p.jornada_partido =  '1'

Comment: @Daniel Si te sirvió la respuesta puedes marcarla como correcta.